# Trying to subtract 1 from a variable, but it's subtracting 3. C# Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reduce an enemy's health by 1 when space is pressed, but when space is pressed, the value is decreased by 3. When the program first runs the variable *enemyHealth* has a value of 4:

[image: When the program first runs]

After space is pressed the variable returns as 1. If space is sequentially pressed the value keeps decreasing by 3:

[image: After space is pressed]

Moving the code that subtracts from enemyHealth to void start yields the same result.

The line of code that subtracts from the enemy's health is running 3 times, which is causing the problem. I, however, have no idea why it's running 3 times.

Player.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject enemy;
    private Enemy enemyScript;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GameObject.Find("Battle_Dummy");
        enemyScript = enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            enemyScript.enemyHealth--;
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int enemyHealth = 4;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding ```Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Damage Enemy");``` immediately before any time you damge (or otherwise modify) the enemy's health.  This will tell you which object the script is attached to and how often it runs. (You can also log ```Time.time``` to see if it's in the same Update)

Comment: @Immersive, after some debugging I have noticed that it is running 3 times, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you attached the behaviour multiple times.

Usually `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` should fire only once and only fire after you released it again. You can try to do somtething like this to remember it fired and reset it manually (although this **should not be needed** according to the documentation):

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject enemy;
    private Enemy enemyScript;
    private bool handledSpaceBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GameObject.Find("Battle_Dummy");
        enemyScript = enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!handledSpaceBar && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            enemyScript.enemyHealth--;
            handledSpaceBar = true;
        }
        if (handledSpaceBar && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            handledSpaceBar = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

See

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: ```GetKeyDown``` is ```true``` only on the first ```Update``` following the key being depressed.  The same for ```GetKeyUp``` but when the key is released.  You are correct about your ```handledSpacebar``` being redundant as it's built into the ```GetKeyDown/GetKeyUp``` functionality.